# Como evitar doble logueo en un sistema con VisualBasic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Estoy haciendo un sistema de un consultorio medico en VisualBasic y no se como hacer que al logearse se mantenga la sesion activada.
Es decir, en la ventana de Login se ingresan el RUT y la contraseña, luego se consulta a la BD para confirmar que sean correctos los datos.
Si son correctos se cierra la ventana de Login y aparece la ventana correspondiente al tipo de usuario (En este caso un doctor)
Ahora, no se como evitar un doble logueo.
Como lo hago para que solo con el primer login, el doctor tenga acceso solo las ordenes de atención correspondientes a su rut.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías crear un **módulo**, dentro de el módulo creas una **variable pública** podría ser booleana y la declaras ***False***, cuando el usuario acceda al sistema cambias el valor de la variable a ***True***, y cambias el valor de la variable a ***False*** cuando el usuario haya cerrado sesión...

Para evitar el doble logueo comparas la variable y si el valor es ***True***, entonces no se podrá acceder al sistema nuevamente... Sino hasta que la variable se encuentre en ***False***.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo de las siguientes maneras:

- Al usuario agrega un campo que acepte 1,0 de nombre EstaLogeado. Dicho campo será encendido/apagado conforme inicie y cierre sesión. Aqui debes tener mucho cuidado la app se cuelga, las validaciones a realizar verifica intensamente.
- Crear una tabla de Logins, donde se vea el ID del usuario, el nombre del usuario, la fecha y hora de inicio de sesión, la fecha y hora de cierre de sesión. Con esto verificas si el usuario anda conectado revisando el último registro de login con el previo registro si hay cierre de sesión.